# Restored WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an option to start my mainwindow minimized.  The window is set to SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight".  when I click to restore the window it opens larger than the initial WidthAndHeight.  I use the following in the MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
   private void WindowStart()
    {
        if (LocalSystem.StartMinimized)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
            ShowInTaskbar = true;
        }
        if (LocalSystem.StartOnTop)
        {
            Topmost = true;
        }
        Activate();
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does this code not work? Where is your `WindowStart` method called from? Are you using MVVM? What is `LocalSystem`?

Comment: when I unminimize the window its larger than it should be. Starting it normally is find and does WidthAndHeight.   It does start minimized.  WindowStart is the last method called in MainWindow().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider keeping track of the state change of your WPF window. Add an event handler of the StateChanged event of your Window and keep track of the Window width and height.

You could keep track of the size of the window like this:

```
public MainWindow() {

 InitializeComponent();
  _lastState = this.WindowState;
  _initialWidth = this.ActualWidth;
  _initialHeight = this.ActualHeight;
   this.StateChanged += Window_StateChanged;
}


    WindowState _lastState;
    double _initialwidth, _initialHeight;

    private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState != _lastState)
        {
          if (_lastState == WindowState.Minimized && this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized){
            this.Width = _initialWidth;
            this.Height = _initialHeight;

           }
           _lastState = this.WindowState;

        }
    }
```

Note the use of ActualHeight and ActualWidth. The Window actual dimensions will be known after InitializeComponent is run inside its constructor. A restored or unminized, as you so eloquently put it, window is window where the State goes from WindowState.Minimized to WindowState.Maximized.

Note that we try to minimize the amount of code behind in WPF apps, as a best practice is to use MVVM. You could though consider creating a WPF behavior class for restoring initial size of Window, after all it is a generic behavior.

Comment: I couldn't get the dimensions to load after initialize, but I was able to get your code working and also my WindowStart by putting them in my Loaded += Window_Load.  I don't know why it works this way.

Also you have two _initialWidth in your event.

Comment: Well, the calculations of the Window layout is done in the Loaded event then. Sorry, I was not near a computer typing my sample code to verify, but if it helped you solve your problem, that is great. Happy WPF-ing. I fixed the double widths typo in the code now.